# Server / Client workflow with socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm starting to learn unix basics at college, i've got an exercise which says something like:"build a client/server application in C in which: the server (tcp socket) print the ip of the client and the text given, and and it shutdown when receives "exit" as string from the client.

Now I've got conceptual problems, i've written these two C program (ignoring for now the text thing...)which i start in two different linux terminal, but the client do nothing, and the server got stuck. I don't understand the whole address thing, what should i put in there (in client)?
 **Long story short: I cannot establish a simple connection**

**SERVER**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main (void){


    struct sockaddr_in mio_indirizzo;
    mio_indirizzo.sin_family= AF_INET;
    mio_indirizzo.sin_port=htons(5200);
    mio_indirizzo.sin_addr.s_addr  = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    int fd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (fd<0) perror("socket"),exit(1);

    int b=bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&mio_indirizzo,sizeof(mio_indirizzo));
    if(b<0) perror("bind"),exit(-1);

    if((listen(fd,5))<0) perror("listen"),exit(-1);

    while(1){

             struct sockaddr indirizzo_client;
             int fd2=accept(fd, &indirizzo_client,NULL);
             if (fd2<0) perror("accept"),exit(-1);
             printf("connection accepted\n");
             close(fd2);
    }

    close(fd);
    shutdown(fd,SHUT_RDWR);
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main (void){
     int fd;
     struct sockaddr_in mio_indirizzo;

    mio_indirizzo.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    mio_indirizzo.sin_port         = htons(5200);
    inet_aton("Putted here the IP of my machine", &mio_indirizzo.sin_addr);

    fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // crea un socket

    connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &mio_indirizzo, sizeof(mio_indirizzo)); // crea la connessione





    close(fd); // chiude il socket 

}
```

Comment: Any errors? What's the actual output of the programs? Nothing on both sides? Also: There are plenty TCP/IP Server/Client examples on the net.

Comment: Apart from the other problems, you're not making any attempt to `read()` from or `write()` to your socket, so no wonder nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1):

In your server, for accept():

```
struct sockaddr indirizzo_client;
int len = sizeof(indirizzo_client);
int fd2=accept(fd, &indirizzo_client, &len);
```

But actually, your program will just print "connection accepted" and quit. You may use select or threads to communicate between the client and the server.

Comment: simply changing that didn't work, but using localhost as address resolved it. But my doubts are all still there.

Comment: Try with : struct sockaddr_in indirizzo_client cast to (struct sockaddr *) in accept() function, also cast len in (socklen_t *) in accept(). Your code seems good anyway.

Comment: It was my mystake, in the client i put the wrong address